# FindWindowEx random failures getting child window handle

Tags: vb.net, winforms, winapi

I have a VB.NET 4.6.1 desktop app that has been using `FindWindow` and `FindWindowEx` for over 2 years with no issue to locate a MDI child window and capture the window caption text, it has worked flawlessly until recent.
The behavior now is my app can only successfully obtain the MDI client window handle if I go back to either the parent window or MDI client and click anywhere on either window, then return to my app and the process succeeds.

I have tried adding threading sleep events, running the action continuously in a loop multiple times, calling `AppActivate` method using process ID (thinking I just needed to execute again), my next workaround thought is to try and send a click event to the parent window prior to my action being executed or maybe to use Enumerate all child windows of the parent, hope someone can suggest something because I am at a roadblock, been doing this for years but this one doesn't make sense to me, I have the suspicion that it is related to recent ownership of the software company and them revising this section, but I have no idea why it would interfere with these root level API methods.

Sample Code:

```vb
MDIhWnd = FindWindowEx(ParenthWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "WindowsForms10.MDICLIENT.app.0.34f5582_r7_ad1", Nothing)
'Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
'AppActivate(proc(0).Id)
If MDIhWnd = 0 Then
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    'Dim hw = GetTopWindow(ParenthWnd)
    For i = 0 To 500
        AppActivate(proc(0).Id)
        MDIhWnd = FindWindowEx(ParenthWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "WindowsForms10.MDICLIENT.app.0.34f5582_r7_ad1", Nothing)
        If MDIhWnd <> 0 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Please show the declaration of `FindWindowEx`. What is `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` after the call? Can you locate the same window with [Spy++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-start-spy-increment?view=vs-2022)?

Comment: Declare Auto Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Integer
    Declare Auto Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwndParent As IntPtr, ByVal hwndChildAfter As IntPtr,
                                                         ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As Integer

Comment: Spy++ always finds the window no problem.

Comment: I have also tried, this type of declaration:     <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint:="FindWindow")>
    Private Shared Function FindWindow(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Private Shared Function FindWindowEx(ByVal parentHandle As IntPtr, ByVal childAfter As IntPtr, ByVal lclassName As String, ByVal windowTitle As String) As IntPtr
    End Function

Comment: Maybe a bit for my own interest and definitely not an answer, but why even do this via winapi for MDI control and not the Inbuilt Mdi methods and properties of WinForms objects?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a problem where [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) is the solution. There's literally no need to hard-code window class names that are clearly dynamically generated.

Comment: This app scrapes window test from a 3rd part app, I am not sure the UI automation would work, and I do not have access to the applications source code, so this is the method we have been using fine for 2 years, now all of sudden it is acting flaky, I kinda wonder if it has anything to do with security patch's like TLS maybe, I have another app that uses a self hosted webservice that has 1 method in a DLL that suddenly quit working also. my step will be to monitor communication channels and the event logs.

Comment: You can use the Inspect.exe tool (part of the Windows SDK) to verify, whether any given application implements the required UIA interfaces. Any program that uses standard controls does. You don't need access to the source code to learn about the UIA interfaces implemented. Frankly, this sounds like you have opted for the wrong solution all along, ignored all the warnings along the way, started to rely on internal implementation details. And now, things *have* changed. Which you knew all along was allowed to happen, without prior notice. Time to evaluate the right solution this time around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was, based on the above suggestion, to use UI Automation, I
had never worked with it before, however after looking it over I gave a go and
found that it did indeed simplify my needs to capture window text from a 3rd party application window with MDI Client Interface.

Below is a lessor version in VB.NET of the process for anyone needing to do the
same thing:

```
Imports System.Windows.Automation
' You will also need references to UIAutomationClient, and UIAutomationTypes

Private Sub test_ui_automation()        
Dim ParenthWnd As Integer = 0
Dim _AutomationElementA As System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement = Nothing
Dim _AutomationElementB As System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement = Nothing
Dim _AutomationElementC As System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement = Nothing
Dim propCondition As Condition

Try
   'Parent Windows Process Stuff
   ParenthWnd = FindWindow(Nothing, "Application to Find")
   _AutomationElementA = AutomationElement.FromHandle(ParenthWnd)

If _AutomationElementA Is Nothing Then  
   NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error
   NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Couldn't Locate Parent Window."
   NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
   NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3000)
   Exit Sub
End If

' MDI Client Stuff
' I used ClassNameProperty but other conditions are available
propCondition = New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "WindowsForms10.MDICLIENT.app.0.34f5582_r7_ad1", PropertyConditionFlags.IgnoreCase)
_AutomationElementB = _AutomationElementA.FindFirst(TreeScope.Element Or TreeScope.Children, propCondition)    

If _AutomationElementB Is Nothing Then
   NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Warning
   NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Application warning MDIClient not Available!"
   NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
   NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3000)
   Exit Sub
End If  

' Final Stage Stuff Locate Window Containing Class with Caption   
propCondition = New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.34f5582_r7_ad1", PropertyConditionFlags.IgnoreCase)
_AutomationElementC = _AutomationElementB.FindFirst(TreeScope.Element Or TreeScope.Children, propCondition)

If _AutomationElementC Is Nothing Then
   NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Warning
   NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Automation warning, MDI Details are open."
   NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
   NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3000)
   Exit Sub
End If

Caption = _AutomationElementC.Current.Name  
' If needed you can now parse/strip any data needed from the Caption text.
' I had other processes here but could not include in the post.

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try

End Sub
```